# SQL Pivot Table with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with work that students have done against requirements i.e

```
 Name  RequirementID RequirementType Completed
 Fred       1            Questions     1
 Fred       2            Portfolio     Null
 Fred       3            Questions     Null
 Fred       4            Portfolio     1
 Mary       1            Questions     Null
 Mary       2            Portfolio     1
 Mary       3            Questions     1
 Mary       4            Portfolio     1
```

I want to place this in a pivot table so that the results are:

```
Name   TotalRequired  Questions   Portfolio
Fred         4            1           1
Mary         4            1           2
```

I can do a straight forward pivot to get the total of the 'Completed' column but I want to know if it is possible to get the 'TotalRequired' figure too.

```
select * from (
select Name,RequirementID,RequirementType,Completed
from Course_Requirements) as s

PIVOT
(Count (Completed) for RequirementType in (Questions, Portfolio)
) as pvt
```

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: how do you calculate totalrequired? count(name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       count(*) as TotalRequired,
       count(case when RequirementType = 'Questions' then completed end) as Questions,
       count(case when RequirementType = 'Portfolio' then completed end) as Portfolio
from Course_Requirements cr
group by name;
```

Comment: I think you need to account for the `Completed` being `1` for each `RequirementType` to get an accurate count.

Comment: @WEI_DBA . . . This is using `COUNT()`, so it should take that into account (I used `COUNT()` because the OP uses that in the question).

Comment: Yup... nvm... I was thinking of the `SUM(Case` scenario... need more coffee!. :-)

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't considered this method

Answer (score 1):

I bet you can do this using a `COUNT() OVER`.

```
select * from (
select Name,RequirementID,RequirementType,Completed,
TotalRequired=COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Name)
from Course_Requirements) as s

PIVOT
(Count (Completed) for RequirementType in (Questions, Portfolio)
) as pvt
```